# Picture Show Preview

Tags: excel, vba, show, preview

I am using the image function to generate the image, in some videos on youtube when you hover over the cell the "Show preview" pops up automatically, but for some reason this option is not working in all my workbooks.

So, I turned to VBA trying to replicate the Cntl+Shift+F5 with SendKeys.The problem with this method it's not reliable because sometimes it triggers the NumLock too.

Is there VBA code to show "Show Preview" of an inserted image in a cell?

[image]

Comment: [ShowCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.showcard) will preview the image

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thank you so much